# What is the most effective structure for appending elements to a List-like collection in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I have to append elements to my collection. Which structure is more preferable? Appending to `List` costs O(n), what about `ListBuffer`, `ArrayBuffer`, `Set`, `Map` and other structures?

Comment: [From the docs.](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/performance-characteristics.html)

Answer (score 2):

[`ListBuffer`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html) accotding to the docs:

> It provides constant time prepend and append.

But it is **mutable** structure, so be careful using - preferably in a very limited scope (e.g. function or method).

[`ArrayBuffer`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html) according to the documentation:

> Prepends and removes are linear in the buffer size.

Because this structure built on top of the dynamic array, hence sometimes require internal array copy for recreation, which in JVM is almost constant but still not exactly constant time. See [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) documentation for more details. Also **mutable** structure.

`Set`, `Map` - are not what you called `List`-like at all. `Set` - un-ordered (list ***IS*** ordered) structure, which contains ONLY unique elements. `Map[K, V]` - stores as the name stands, the mapping between `K` type keys to `V` type values.

*So as conclusion*: if you need to `append` elements I'd suggest to go with `ListBuffer`, but since this is mutable structure limit scope its usage ad whenever you need to pass it somewhere - convert it to `List`.